# How to make a Standard Scratch Guide?

Tags: java

Hi I'm a beginner at coding and I've just tried my first project. It's a standard scratch score for golf. Everytime I've run the code it comes sout with a completely wrongly score. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StandardScratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double Par1 = 0.0,
        Par2 = 0.0,
        Par3 = 0.0, 
        difficulty = 0.0;
        String operation;
        Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many par 3 holes are there?");
        Par1 = scannerObject. nextDouble();

        System.out.println("How many par 4 holes are there?");
        Par2 = scannerObject. nextDouble(); 

        System.out.println("How many par 5 holes are there?");
        Par3 = scannerObject. nextDouble();

        System.out.println("What is the difficulty adjustment for the course?");
        difficulty = scannerObject. nextDouble();

        System.out.println("The Standard Scratch for the course is:" + ((Par1 * 6) + (Par2 * 4) + (Par3 * 5) - difficulty));    
    }   
}
```

When every I try to run the code with the numbers being 6,10,2 and -2 it comes out with 88 while the true score should be 66. Thanks!

Comment: What is a *"scratch score"*?

Comment: Why should it be 66? 6 * 6 + 10 * 4 + 2 * 5 - (-2) = 36 + 40 + 10 + 2 = 88.

Comment: how do you get 66 ? 6 * 6 + 10 * 40 + 2 * 5 - (-2) = 88

Comment: Also, I strongly suggest you use lower-case names for your variables (`par1` instead of `Par1` etc)

Comment: Actually, they should be `par3`, `par4` and `par5` ... for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've coded this:

```
 ... Par1 * 6 ...
```

The scratch score for a par-3 hole in golf is actually 3.

It doesn't help that you have used misleading names for your variables.